# Windows Batch Script get Substring with always same structure

Tags: batch-file

I was wondering if there is a way to get always the same substring out of a string in windows batch file? I will give you an example what I am trying to do:

Lets say I have following strings

```
INSERT INTO [Models] ([Id], [Name], [MakeId]) VALUES ('6b29d7cd-224b-4c81-9bb8-597b5b771ae8', 'Scirocco 2l GT', '26422e04-95bd-43f9-923a-9e3b16e8456f')
INSERT INTO [Models] ([Id], [Name], [MakeId]) VALUES ('3bc65d09-0602-42a1-ab68-7ad7bc0615c5', 'Santana GLS', '26422e04-95bd-43f9-923a-9e3b16e8456f')
INSERT INTO [Models] ([Id], [Name], [MakeId]) VALUES ('b5cb64c8-78e7-47ff-95e8-dce7d2482112', 'Kübel 181', '26422e04-95bd-43f9-923a-9e3b16e8456f')
INSERT INTO [Models] ([Id], [Name], [MakeId]) VALUES ('de6f6495-edb6-4dcc-8aa6-a60b362d7280', 'Transporter T3 TD', '26422e04-95bd-43f9-923a-9e3b16e8456f')
```

I have always such an INSERT INTO String but I couldnt figure out how to trim this string, if even possible, so I have only the Name value left, like `Scirocco 2l GT` or `Santana GLS`

I have the following code, it reads every single line into a variable and then I need to get the substring. But here is where I am stuck, I dont know how to get the substring I need

```
@echo off
set "File2Read=sqlstrings.txt"
If Not Exist "%File2Read%" (Goto: Error)
rem This will read a file into an array of variables and populate it 
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Type "%File2Read%"') do (
    set /a count+=1
    set "Line[!count!]=%%a"
)
rem Display array elements
For /L %%i in (1,1,%Count%) do (
    rem echo "Var%%i" is assigned to ==^> "!Line[%%i]!"
    for /F [delims=,] %%G IN ("!Line[%%i]!") DO 
)
pause>nul
Exit
```

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? Please provide a [mcve] of your code!

Comment: @aschipfl I have edit my code

Comment: You need to define some criteria by which to exttract the sub-strings; for example, you could extract the fourth comma-separated token by a [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html), then remove everything up to the first apostrophy and finally get everything before the next apostrophy; would this always suit your data?

Comment: @aschipfl Yes this would always fit my data, thanks for the suggestion. I did edit my code, but how I tell my code to take the data after the 4th comma?

Comment: Where did you get this syntax from: `for /F [delims=,]`? it must read `for /F "delims=,"`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the following code:

```cmd
@echo off
> nul chcp 1252
for /F "tokens=4 delims=, eol=," %%J in ('^> nul chcp 437 ^& type "test.txt"') do (
    for /F "tokens=2 delims=' eol='" %%I in (" %%J") do (
        echo(%%I
    )
)
```

This first extracts the fourth comma-separated tokens, which are (note the leading <kbd>SPACE</kbd>):

> ```cmd
>  'Scirocco 2l GT'
>  'Santana GLS'
>  'Kübel 181'
>  'Transporter T3 TD'
> ```

Then it extracts the second apostrophy-separated tokens, which are the names of interest:

> ```cmd
> Scirocco 2l GT
> Santana GLS
> Kübel 181
> Transporter T3 TD
> ```

The code-page switching in the code is done to display the `ü` in one of the sub-strings correctly.

Comment: the data strings are consistent, so `for /f "tokens=4 delims='" %%a in (sqlstrings.txt) do echo %%a` should be ok (unless the hexadecimal things could be empty)

Comment: Yes, @Stephan, that's for sure easier, but at the end it depends on the real data, which we don't know...

Comment: ... as most of the times. `:/`